# LibGDX: Issue with unitScale for Tiled and Box2D

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, tilemap, scale

I've got the following: I use a `TiledMap` (loaded from a `.tmx`), each tile 32x32 pixels in size and generate the Box2D bodies for collision from the TiledMap's `ObjectLayer`. That all works fine, no errors or issues. The only thing is a very strange behavior of the `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer`: It gets a `unitScale` with the value `1 / 32` (because one unit is 32 pixels) as advised on the LibGDX GitHub wiki page. The same unit scale is used for Box2D. Thought in theory this should work just fine it renders the map very small (same is the case for the Box2D bodies, they're shown very small by the `Box2DDebugRenderer`):

[image]

Here is my code (more or less simplified):

```
public class MainScreen {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private ScreenViewport viewport;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private World world;
    private TiledMap tiledMap;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

    public MainScreen() {
        this.batch = new SpriteBatch();
        this.world = new World(new Vector2(), true);
        float unitScale = 1.0f / Constants.TILE_SIZE;

        this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        this.camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * unitScale, 
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * unitScale);   
        this.viewport = new ScreenViewport(this.camera);
        this.tiledMap = (new TiledMapLoader()).load("level/test-level.tmx");
        this.tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(this.tiledMap,
            unitScale, this.batch);

        // Create bodies in world based on map
        Collisions.create(this.world, this.map, unitScale);
    }

    public void render(float delta) {      
        // Clear the screen
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        this.world.step(delta, 6, 2);
        this.camera.update();              
        this.tiledMapRenderer.setView(this.camera);
        this.tiledMapRenderer.render();
    }

    public void resize(int w, int h) {            
        this.viewport.update(w, h);            
    }
}
```

I've got no idea why this is happening... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the picture showing?

Comment: @Anko That's the screen content (including the rendered map and the debug renderer objects).

Comment: Why do you have a `unitScale` on the renderer ? What does that achieve ? What you are doing is drawing everything 32 times smaller. Instead, you want to render the world as-is from tiled map. Why change it ? You don't want to be using a `unitScale` for the renderer.

Comment: @Shiro I read that on the wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps#rendering-tiled-maps - There it says "`The unit scale tells the renderer how many pixels map to a single world unit.`".

Comment: Huh... I think you are missing `this.batch.setProjectionMatrix(this.camera.combined);` before creating the renderer. You are passing the batch without first setting its projection matrix.

Comment: @Shiro I tested that, but it doesn't do anything. The projection matrix is set when calling `setView(camera)` on the renderer.

Comment: Could you please edit the code so that you display a minimalistic example of the problem ? You have an `OrthographicCamera` that you have `setTo(false, width, height)`, and a `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer` that you `setView(this.camera)` and then `render()`. So basically 3-4 lines of code ? And for some reason it doesn't work ? From the code you show, I don't see something wrong.

Comment: @Shiro I simplified it as much as possible. It has to be caused by the camera (or viewport) in some way, since the box2d bodes are in the right aspect ratio to the tiles...

Comment: Does this work with `new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(this.tiledMap, 1, batch);` ?

Comment: @Shiro It does. (But that way the box2d bodies stay small). Also, it seems as if the small area (shown by the image above) is 32 by 32 pixels...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just stumbled upon the answer:

I checked my `ScreenViewport` and seemingly the viewport somehow ignores the `setToOrtho(false, width, height)` and the method `setUnitsPerPixel(unitScale)` has to becalled first...

I never saw an example in which a viewport was used together with box2d, tilemap and unitScale, so I didn't even know about that method.

The greatest thanks to @Shiro for his help! :)

Comment: I always use a `FitViewport` and I didn't have this problem before. As for the box2d bodies that were "staying small" it is because we only changed the `unitScale` to 1 just for the renderer only just to see what is wrong. I think that the screenshot you show was 32x32 cause your resolution was 1024x1024. So, 32 times smaller becomes only 32x32.

Comment: @Shiro The problem with the box2d bodies is now solved too, everything is now zoomed and displayed properly :) So in fact there was nothing wrong with the code, but one call was missing...