# LibGDX: Content appears stretched although I'm using a ScreenViewport

Tags: libgdx, camera, viewport

I just fixed [another issue](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/108040/64492) regarding the scaling inside a `ScreenViewport`. And yet another problem arises:

If I'm understanding the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#screenviewport) correctly, a `ScreenViewport` does not scale or stretch the content in any way. In my case it somehow does:

When the game is started, it looks like this:

[image]

And after resizing the window (e.g. making it wider) it looks like this (obviously stretched...):

[image]

(The code is mostly still the same as in the [linked question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/108040/64492)).

Since I couldn't find a example of using a `ScreenViewport` with `unitScale` yet, I have no idea how to make this work... Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to make it work I needed to call [`useCustomViewport(x, y, width, height)`](https://github.com/libgdx/box2dlights/wiki/Custom-viewport-and-box2dlights) on the `rayHandler` inside of `resize(width, height)`.

Comment: I downvoted this because Andrej posted the answer two hours before you answered your own. He could not have known you where calling your viewport `useCustomViewport` without seeing your code. Accept his and delete this one to get rep back.

Comment: @MennoGouw My code is linked in my question... [see](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/108040/64492)

Comment: @MennoGouw Also, the `useCustomViewport` was causing this strange display behavior, since I didn't call it in `resize` and my constructor.

Comment: I overlooked that. But still the answer of Andrej is proper.

Comment: @MennoGouw It's totally valid, but I did call `viewport.update(width, height)`, so that wasn't the cause, which means that his suggestion wasn't the solution.

Comment: I have looked at your code and nowhere I can find `useCustomViewport`. It's a `Viewport` right? Then obviously if you are using that viewport you have to call it on that. I stand by my original statement.

Comment: @MennoGouw It's not in my code because it was missing at that point. That was why I started this question. I experienced the strange displaying behavior and did not know why it was happening. But after some more research I figured out that the `useCustomViewport` method has to be called when using a viewport with box2dlights. I didn't know that, so I didn't call it, so it wasn't in my code before. I also saw no point in updating my previous code with `setCustomViewport` after finding out about it, as it is irrelevant for my previous question.

Comment: @MennoGouw Still, I can't mark an answer as the right one if it hasn't helped my to solve my issue. :/

Answer (score 1):

You should call viewport.update(width, height); inside resize method of screen.

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
}
```

More info here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: I did that, but the `resize(width, height)` call wasn't forwarded properly to the screen. That's solved now, but now the viewport is only displayed correctly when resizing (it's flickering between the right viewport scale and the stretched behavior...).

Comment: Ok, I figured out that it's caused by rendering the `RayHandler`...